# PDF files no longer upload with firebase deploy

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

My angularjs app hosted pdf files in the past. But lately they will not upload. I had hosted the pdf docs in the lib directory and even in root directory of app; but they do not load.

Can anyone suggest a fix?

Here is my firebase.json file. I removed app name.

```
"firebase": "nnnnnnnnnn",
"public": ".",   
"ignore": [
   "firebase.json",
   "**/.*",
   "**/node_modules/**"
] }
```

Comment: Thanks Frrank.. the documentation says files beginning with a period will be ignored by **/.*. But I will try your suggestion

Comment: The firebase.json file was not the probelm. The problem was casued by including blank characters in the file name. For example I used Help Doc.pdf.  When I changed the file name to Help-Doc.pdf the file was found. Probably a typical error by a newbie to web development. Sorry to trouble you. But another newbie might benefit from my mistake.

Comment: Great that you found it. Can you provide it as an answer? Self-answering is encouraged here on StackOverflow and allows you to build reputation.